# How to check if price contains "-" in python

Tags: python

Hey guys i am trying to solve this problem, i have searched on stackoverflow but didn't find the correct answer,  so i have `price` and it contains

> $250.88 - $650.86

or

> $650.86

i want to find if the given `price` has `-` in it then condition become true and remove the `$250.88 -` and only print

> 680.86

here is the code i wrote but it is not working :

```
price = '$250 - $650.86'
if (price[price.rfind('-'):]):
    val  = price[price.rfind('-'):]
    trim = re.compile(r'[^\d.,]+')
    price2 = trim.sub('', val)
else:
    price2 = trim.sub('', price)
print(price2)
```

Comment: I'd suggest just use `rfind` in this case. `price = price[price.rfind('$'):]`

Comment: `price.rsplit('-', 1)[-1].strip(' $')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it more simple by using `split`, like below:

```
>>> price = '$250 - $650.86'
>>> s = price.split('-')
>>> price2 = s[0].strip() if len(s) == 1 else s[1].strip()
>>> print(price2)
$650.86
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal glad to help

Answer (score 2):

```
testcases = [
'$250.88 - $650.86',
'$650.86',
'$568.6'
]

for case in testcases:
    price = case.split('-')[-1].replace('$', '').strip()
    print(price)
```

Prints:

```
650.86
650.86
568.6
```

To check if `-` is in `price` string, you can use `-` operator:

```
testcases = [
'$250.88 - $650.86',
'$650.86',
'$568.6'
]

for case in testcases:
    price = case.split('-')[-1].replace('$', '').strip()

    if '-' in case:
        print('Price "{}" contains -'.format(case))
    else:
        print('Price "{}" doesn\'t contain -'.format(case))

    print(price)
```

Prints:

```
Price "$250.88 - $650.86" contains -
650.86
Price "$650.86" doesn't contain -
650.86
Price "$568.6" doesn't contain -
568.6
```

Comment: i want to use if condition because i am not using an array for example if price = '$568.6'  this does not work

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal I updated my answer. To check if `-` is in price, you can use `in` operator. I added price `$568.6` to testcases

Answer (score 0):

Your code is overly complicated. Python has a nice feature where you can easily check if an object is part of an iterable, so in your case we can check if a string is in another string:

```
if '-' in price:
   ...
```

edit: Second part of the problem

Since you're already using the re module:

```
if '-' in price:
    matches = re.findall(r'\$(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', price)
    print(matches[-1])
else:
   print(price.strip('$'))
```

The regular expression would work regardless of if there the minus is there or not but REs tend to be a bit slow so I'd avoid using them if I can.

Comment: The second part of the problem was missed.  If in your code block you carry about a split, it will only want the second indexed item.

Comment: There we go. I've added a second part.

Answer (score 0):

You could `find` the index of `-` and return a substring, or the string if `-` is not present

```
price = '$250 - $650.86'


def get_last_part(p):
    i = price.find('-')
    if i > 0:
        return p[i+1:].strip()
    return p


print(get_last_part(price))
print(get_last_part('$250'))
```

If you want to remove the dollar sign too, you could pass that to strip
`.strip('- $')`

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this:

```py
price = '$250 - $650.86'
if '-' in price:
    print(price.split()[-1])
else:
    print(price.split()[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if '-' in price:
    price.strip()
    c = price.rfind('-')
    c = c+1
    price2 = price[c:]
else:
    price 2 = trim.sub('',price)
print(price2)
```

This one i think will do and is a short solution.

Answer (score 0):

one liner

```
testcases = [
'$250.88 - $650.86',
'$650.86',
'$568.6'
]

[ i.split('-')[-1] for i in testcases ]
```